# SQL Sub string Right char index

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
        input 
       -----------
        '12345-123'
        '3456-67'


       output
      ----------- 
      column 1    column 2
        12345       123
         3456        67
```

In SQL For Column 1  :

```
  SELECT  Substring('12345-123',1,CHARINDEX('-','12345-123')-1)
```

For column 2 : unable to achieve ? can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to accomplish both columns using reverse(), keeps the logic identical.

```
SELECT  Substring('12345-123',1,CHARINDEX('-','12345-123')-1) col1, reverse(Substring(reverse('12345-123'),1,CHARINDEX('-',reverse('12345-123'))-1)) col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use string manipulation:

```
select left(input, charindex('-', input) - 1) as col1,
       stuff(input, 1, charindex('-', input), '') as col2
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=46555b73eea533d63bd2e280d2bf9d64) is a db<>fiddle.